# Cannot find pre-configured RAID array after installing Ubuntu Server 18.04.3

Tags: server, raid

My colleagues and I are trying to set up a local database system that handles a fair amount of Geospatial Data in the form of large raster arrays. We figured that having a local machine with Ubuntu Server edition on it and a 10TB RAID1 array would satisfy our needs. We had the machine built by a local shop that set up the RAID1 configuration for us.

Fast forward to us installing Ubuntu Server on it. The installation detected the SSD that we bought for installing the OS, but it did not detect the RAID1 array even though it is showing up in BIOS and we see a dialog message for our RAID1 array being set up before the BIOS is loaded. Similarly after installation the RAID array does not show up after using utilities like df to check how much disk space is available.

When trying to run the commands `sudo fdisk -l` this is what we get:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2A303527-8A88-4091-88D9-704865E7287D

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 2549760 488396799 485847040 231.7G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: 231.7 GiB, 248751587328 bytes, 485842944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/sccdb--System--Product--NameSCCDB--vg-root: 230.7 GiB, 247673651200 bytes, 483737600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/sccdb--System--Product--NameSCCDB--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

And when running `lspci -knn | grep 'RAID bus controller'` we get:

```
01:00.1 RAID bus controller [0104]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43bd] (rev 01)
0a:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:7916] (rev 61)
```

I am not sure how I am supposed to set up Ubuntu in the first place to recognize the RAID1 array that should already be there. How would we go about finding and mounting the array? Should we undo the BIOS setup and set it up in software? Is there a way to modify the existing installation to find it so that we don't have to reinstall everything again?

I can give more information as needed. Thanks in advance.